# Can you recommend a book to learn to teach math to a child?

Tags: education, book-recommendation

I am looking for a book which contains some ideas on introducing a child to mathematics. I am *not particularly* looking for a textbook to be used *as part of the teaching* (though feel free to mention one if it's particularly good), but for a book suggesting teaching methods and approaches (the ultimate purpose is homeschooling).

Crucially, the emphasis should be on actually teaching mathematics, not grinding through mindless exercises (in the spirit of Paul Lockhart's [Mathematician's Lament](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/LockhartsLament.pdf)).

Clarification: I am looking for material that focuses on teaching children which are already old enough to be proficient with counting and some basic arithmetic but maybe not ready yet to eat a lot of formalism, so in the 5-12 year old range?)

Comment: This is a good question, but it would be helpful to know roughly what age and/or level of mathematics we're talking about. I understand the request is for books to help teach math, but knowing the type of math we're talking about is relevant.

Comment: I'll add a clarification

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might be interested in looking at the archives of the Los Angeles Math Circle to find interesting and challenging math handouts for elementary school students.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Math From Three To Seven](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/mcl-5) by Alexander Zvonkin is an excellent book that chronicles the author's experiences running a math circle for his children and their friends from the ages 3 to 7.  It does not purport to be an instruction manual, but there are many great ideas and all activities are described in detail.  [Here's a preview](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/mcl-5-prev.pdf).

And just to give some credence to his lessons' effect: his son Dimitri is also a mathematician!

Comment: Wonderful, I actually posted an link to an excerpt of this book, but I didn't know what the book was. I think I actually may have had Dimitri as a "colleur" in 2000.

Comment: The full book seems available here: http://www.msri.org/people/staff/levy/files/MCL/Zvonkin.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The book ["Beast Academy"](https://www.beastacademy.com) which have been published by a very well know Company " Art of Problem Solving".
in the discretion they said its good for kids in grade 3rd. but I used with my son in 1rd grade and he like it. 
The most important this about this book which also is series. its fun ( nice colorful Cartoon) and its total different from what they teach it in school. as a dad and Ph.D student I still enjoy every part of this book.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I have some online mathematics exercises / tutorials (autocorrected), ranging from kindergarten to college, at: http://www.public-domain-materials.com/folder-student-exercise-tasks-for-mathematics-language-arts-etc---autocorrected.html

Also, the material is public-domain. You can copy the entire website if you like and alter it to fit your own purposes.

edit: Also: [DadsWorksheets.com](http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/temo-dadsworksheetscom.html):

"This site has math fact worksheets, place value problems, addition without
carrying, subtraction without borrowing, suites of multiplication tests using
various methodologies, fractions and more. It’s done wonders for my kids.
I hope it does the same for yours."

Answer (score -1):

The best book I have found so far is Polya's "How to solve it."

This article has also seems like a great resource: http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/mcl-5-prev.pdf

Comment: You might consider to expand your question to contain a bit more information on the book and why it is good.

Comment: Seriously? Polya for 5-12 year olds?

Comment: The book is for the teacher, not the child. And yes, that particular book is appropriate for your purpose. Think instead of patttern matching.